# How to create a Gremlin DSL in javascript?

Tags: gremlin

How can I create Domain Specific Gremlin steps in javascript? Like this:

```
g.V().user(789).knows(15)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to 3.4.2 there really wasn't an official way besides monkey-patching. Since 3.4.2 (set to release this week) changes have been made to the API to make DSL building more of a first class citizen - the approach is discussed in the [reference documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.2-SNAPSHOT/reference/#gremlin-javascript-dsl).